# How to send ctrl+c signal to a process in JAVA

Tags: java, signals, exec, processbuilder

I am sending signal to a child process in JAVA on windows environment using command

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -SIGINT "+Integer.toString(pid));
```

but it's giving me error, can not run program kill, what am i doing wrong, how can i do this?

Any help will be appreciated! 
THANKS:-)

Answer (score 0):

As there is not a platform independent way to kill a process, you can not use KILL on windows.

The Process class has a `destroy()` method that you can use.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()

**Update**
If what you want is to explicitly/programmaticly kill another program/process of any kind, within the SysInternals' pstools there is a small tool named "pskill" that behaves just like Unixen "kill" would do.

When user selects the task from Windows Task Manager and clicks "End Task", the OS will send WM_CLOSE. If you use "End Process", though, the process is killed directly, no messages sent ever.

Comment: Thanks, But I knew it, I do not want to destroy the process directly, i want to send it a ctrl+C signal, in which i will catch that signal, perform certain tasks than exit. :)
Hope this will give you a clear image. . .

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute command with forcefully option. Try this modified command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -f -SIGINT "+Integer.toString(pid));
```

Hope this will help you.